# Splitting a document on artboards into separate documents. (adobe illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How save from one document all artboard to individual documents (in ai format).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for trying to help. But I myself remembered how to break a document on artboards. This is done simply:
1 - use the comand -Save as-
In the menu that appears, the checkbox "use artboards" is not active. But it's not scary. You need to click "Save"
2 - In the next menu that appears, check the checkbox:
"Save each artboard in a separate file"

Mission complete. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Illustrator EPS format? 
You can save all your Artboards by choosing: File -> Save As.. -> Illustrator EPS and then check box "Use Artboards" and select "Range"

Answer (score 0):

Note: I Use adobe Illustrator CS6 I dont know it the new versions are capable of doing it in AI format

In CS6 I also cannot save artboards directly in AI format but you have an Option for EPS and SVG which is also 100% vector and layers are kept tidy/arranged.

For me I do it in a long method. You may try it if you want to. Shown are screenshots of what options we can use.

[image]

Like yours I have no option for artboards to Ai.
[image]

But you can use EPS, SVG or PDF Instead (it will retain the vector). Be sure to check Use Artboards (select all or specific boards or details only)

[image]

Re-open the EPS files and delete unwanted areas then save now for Ai.
Or better rename the artboard files as <>.ai directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you save your file, simply check the "Save each artboard to a separate file" checkbox. This can be found when the Illustrator Options window pops up while saving your file to the .ai format.

[image]